# How to add Bookmarks to PDF when Merging in Itext7

Tags: c#, itext7

I am trying to create a program that merges several pdfs and has a bookmark to each of them.

My starting method is :

```
    private Byte[] MergePdfForms(Dictionary<string, Stream> files)
    {
        var dest = new MemoryStream();
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);

        foreach (var keyValuePair in files)
        {
               //TODO add bookmark to this page 
            PdfDocument firstSourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(keyValuePair.Value));
            merger.Merge(firstSourcePdf, 1, firstSourcePdf.GetNumberOfPages());
            firstSourcePdf.Close();
        }

        pdf.Close();
        return dest.ToArray();
    }
```

I have tried things like

```
  pdf.InitializeOutlines();
  pdf.AddNamedDestination("Test Bookmark", pdf.GetLastPage().GetPdfObject());
```

Which doesn't create any bookmarks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the example here: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents/clone-merging-documents-bookmarks

```
    private byte[] MergePdfForms(Dictionary<string, Stream> files)
    {
        var dest = new MemoryStream();
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);
        PdfOutline rootOutline = pdf.GetOutlines(false);
        PdfOutline helloWorld = rootOutline.AddOutline("Root");

        int pages = 1;
        foreach (var keyValuePair in files)
        {
            var firstSourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(keyValuePair.Value));
            var subPages = firstSourcePdf.GetNumberOfPages();
            merger.Merge(firstSourcePdf, 1, subPages);
            firstSourcePdf.Close();

            var link1 = helloWorld.AddOutline(keyValuePair.Key);
            link1.AddDestination(PdfExplicitDestination.CreateFit(pdf.GetPage(pages)));
            pages += subPages;

        }
        pdf.Close();
        return dest.ToArray();
    }
```